# How to develop both nextjs and nodejs project to vercel?

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, deployment, vercel

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tYJI.png)

I've a project where the client part is in nextjs and it also has it's APIs, but there is also another folder server which is in nodejs/express for websockets connections. Now I want to deploy my project. How can I deploy both the folders?

I tried creating a vercel.json file like this,

```
{
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/api/(.*)", "dest": "/server/$1" },
    { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/client/$1" }
  ]
}
```

But it didn't work out.

Expectation 1-
Both can be deployed to vercel.
Or, they can be deployed separated.

Comment: Please add more details like server file names of both, please what do you mean by deploying both.